# Get download link of uploaded public file

Tags: c#, .net, dropbox-api

How can I get the download link of the uploaded file?

Lets say that I upload this file:

```
var file = api.UploadFile("dropbox", @"Public\Test.txt", @tmpFile);
```

where tmpFile is a local computer file. How do I get the download link of the file `@"Public\Test.txt"`? It should be something like: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/81990845/Test.txt

Answer (score 1):

The kind of link that you included as a sample is from a Dropbox "Public" folder, but this feature isn't part of the API, and isn't available by default to new users, so you won't want to rely on this.

Instead, you should use the /shares call:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#shares

(This is implemented in all the official SDKs, and is usually available in third party libraries too.) This call returns a shareable link for this feature:

https://www.dropbox.com/help/167/en

By default, these links show a "preview" page where the user can share or download the file, but if you need a "direct" link (like those from the Public folder), you can modify these links as shown here:

https://www.dropbox.com/help/201/en

Comment: I have tried multiple times to use the /shares call, but it doesn't get me the link. Could you explain how to use it?

Comment: Could you elaborate as to what you tried and what happened? Did you get an error message?

Comment: I tried literally how it says there `https://api.dropbox.com/1/shares/<root>/<path>`, with the correct root and path, but I get `{"error": "Invalid OAuth request."}`

Comment: This call needs to be signed using OAuth just like any other (for OAuth 1: oauth_token, oauth_signature, etc.) You'd definitely be best off letting your SDK/library do this for you though. What library are you using? For example, if this is DropNet, it looks like the method is named GetShare.

Comment: I'm using the REST api, code from: http://cgeers.com/2012/03/11/dropbox-rest-api-part-5-file-upload/#more-3965 and he/she didn't make a share method.